# Gear stick not shifting after start?

Tags: transmission, gear-stick

Civic coupe vti 1999.

When In off position, accessories and on gear stick shifts ok.  After start really struggle to put in gears if I can shift to a gear at all.

Edit: ok so I have just found there was no clutch fluid.  I have added clutch fluid and it has made a difference however it still does not go into gear smoothly and struggles at times, especially when goIng downhill, though clutch fluid has made a difference and it is shifting a lot better now.

I couldn’t see any fluid in the clutch container and topped it down however is it the case that maybe old contaminated fluid is further down and this is still causing it to struggle a bit.

Please help me, I’s my transmission gone??  What do I do now?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually when it will shift without the engine running, but won't once it is, the fault is due to the clutch not disengaging (whether fully or partially). This could be because of the clutch itself or because of the master/slave not working correctly (or maladjusted).

Comment: @PAULSTER2 sorry paul. I’ve just let the car roll off the slope and onto flat ground it’s shift big better now. Would this be transmission fluid or related to the clutch as you say. I have just checked for clutch fluid(which I think is used by master/slave)

Comment: Not going to be something internal to the transmission. I'm still looking at the master/slave issue, or a problem with disengagement.

Comment: @PAULSTER2 if my observation is correct, why might being on a slope worsen this in relation to master slave cylinder?  Also could it be the clutch fluid is just too old and needs charging??  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that happen recently (on a Mitsubishi Eclipse) and unfortunately the end result was transmission internals.  Once we ruled out the hydraulic system and the clutch itself the transmission was sent out where they found that the 1st, 3rd, and 5th gear synchros had all suffered catastrophic failure to the point where the car could not be put into gear when running.  A rebuild and it's smooth as butter now.

Comment: Could not changing transmission oil have caused this to happen or what else could have caused it?

Comment: Also did your gear shifts better when you were on flat ground rather than a slope?  Hope u can answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesWilson  Not changing transmission oil is certainly not going to help things, but if it's a direct contributor in your case I can't say.  Hopefully yours turns out to be one of the simpler external causes...  Unfortunately we don't have sloped ground around here.  It's flat as flat can be, so I can't really say...